# How to access the .resx strings for javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, resx

I'm developing a app in .net mvc and I am using the concept of Localisation by having a separate .resx file for flexibility of being able to organize the strings quickly and efficiently. And in the process, I'm having e few javascript code, that has some alerts and confirm boxes being displayed on certain actions. I do not have a separate .js file but just had embedded the code into the .cshtml file. My question is, Cant i take these alert and confirm messages from the .resx file as well?.. I have alreday browsed a lot and no fruitful result of how to use the .resx string within the javascript code? i tried something like,

```
              <script type="javascript">
              var confirm_text= @ResourceLocalisation.ConfirmText
              var confirmText=confirm(confirm_text);
              if(confirmText==true)
              .....
```

But this dint work.. What am I missing?.. Can Someone help me achieve localistion for javascript code?..
My question may be a dupe of,
[How to get texts from Resx to be used in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465844/how-to-get-texts-from-resx-to-be-used-in-javascript)?
but I'm posting this only because I dint get my question answered in this post..

Is there some configuration that i should be doing in **web.config** file aswell ?..

Thanks in Advance..;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do that all the time, and it works properly for us.  Can you show a copy of the HTML generated?  Also, the text should be quoted.

```
@model MyModel
@using My.App.ResourcesProject  // if needed

<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "@LocalizedStrings.AlertText";
    alert(str);
</script>
```